# Excel - provide total across multiple users

Tags: excel, sum

I have a table showing # of hours worked for each user by expense type.  Some users have only 1 entry while others have multiple.  How can I generate table that shows total for each user?

Column 1 is user name, column 2 is # of hours

john doe  100
john doe  20
john doe  50
jane doe  120
bill doe  75
bill doe  25
bill doe  25

Comment: Use pivot table.

Comment: i tried that but message indicates that too many duplicates to create pivot table

Comment: can you share the error message? Take a screenshot

Comment: i was able to get it to work.

Comment: @Kate glad to hear you got it to work. Post your answer here to help others that have a similar question for future reference. If it's a good enough of an answer you might even get upvotes to increase your reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: a bit embarrassed to admit solution.  Instead of using the Recommended Pivot table option, I inserted pivot table and manually configured and that worked

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical job for the subtotals feature of Excel, which can count, sum, calculate the average, ... of groups of data, grouped by an identifier. More explanation can be found in [this official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a).